# How to change ip address for Solace VMR?

Tags: solace

After setting up the solace vmr, it automatically gives you a default ip address. I have tried to change it through:
    enable > configure > ip vrf management > interface intf0 static > ip-address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
But after I do 
    show ip vrf management
nothing is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to version 8.1 of the VMR, it was possible to change the static IP address through the CLI as you have described. The last step is to disable DHCP to allow for the new static IP address to take effect.

The full steps for changing the IP in VMR versions 8.0 and earlier are:

1. Log into the VMR as `sysadmin` through the VM console.
2. Enter the following command to enter the Solace router CLI:

   `[support@solace ~]$ solacectl cli`
3. Enter the following commands:

   `System Software. SolOS-TR Version 7.2.x.x
   Virtual Message Router (Message Routing Node)
   Copyright 2004-2017 Solace Corporation. All rights reserved.
   ip-172-31-2-108> enable
   ip-172-31-2-108# configure
   ip-172-31-2-108(configure)# ip vrf management
   ip-172-31-2-108(configure/ip/vrf)# interface intf0:1
   ip-172-31-2-108(configure/ip/vrf/interface)# ip-address <ip-address/xx>
   ip-172-31-2-108(configure/ip/vrf/interface)# exit
   ip-172-31-2-108(configure/ip/vrf)# route default <ip-address>
   ip-172-31-2-108(configure/ip/vrf)# no dhcp`

The new static IP address will take effect immediately.

In versions 8.1 and later of the VMR, it is not possible to change the IP using the CLI. The IP must be configured on the host or through the cloud provider.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to set the ip on version 8.1 please? The VMR is currently on vSphere Web Client

Comment: @chey Please see the new documentation on how to set the IP with version 8.1 in the host, available here:
http://docs.solace.com/Solace-VMR-Set-Up/Configuring-Interfaces-on-VMR-Hosts.htm
You will need to log on to the VMR host as sysadmin and assign the IP address by editing the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<intf> file as described in the documentation.